# Autocomplete dropdown - submit on click/enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-autocomplete, html-input

Somewhere I found an autocomplete script which suits me perfectly, but there is one thing that I don't know how to change. When you click on something in dropdown it doesn't submit this string, you have to click to select the string and after that click on submit button or press enter. I would like this dropdown autocomplete to submit selected string on click or when pressing enter. This is the code:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ac.css" />    
        <script src="./java/jquery182.js"></script>    
        <script src="./java/jqueryui.js"></script>    
        <script>    
        $(function() {        
        var availableTags = [            
        "Car",   
        "Gun",
        "Apple",
        "Example"]; 

         $( "#txt" ).autocomplete({            
         source: availableTags        
         }); 
         });   
         </script>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        <!-- 
        function enter(e){ 
        if(e.keyCode == 13) 
        { 
        doSomething(); 
        return false; 
        } 
        } 
        //--> 
        </script> 


<input class="ui-widget" id="txt" type="text" onkeypress="return enter(event);">
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="doSomething()">Submit</button>
```

Function `doSomething();` has to be there because I need it. This function: `onkeypress="return enter(event);"` is here so that when enter is pressed, value gets submitted to the `doSomething();` function. There are 2 Javascript documents (jquery182.js and jqueryui,js) which have around 10,000 lines of code so I had to upload them here: http://speedy.sh/a67xR/java-files.zip Hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure the onclick/select behaviour in the call to `autocomplete`, try this:

```
$( "#txt" ).autocomplete({            
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
        doSomething();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: tryed it out and it works only in firefox and opera but only when enter is pressed, on click dosent react on any browser

Comment: What does the HTML look like after the page has loaded (i.e. after the `autocomplete()` function has done its thing)? I'm guessing it's different from the demo on the jquery ui page and therefore my selector isn't accurate.

Comment: You could try putting `$("#ui-id-1 li a").on('click', function() { codeAddress(); });` after `$("#address").autocomplete({ source:availableTags });`

Comment: ..you have to configure it in the call to `autocomplete` ... see edited answer (in a bit)..